# How to show sentence word by word in a separate line

Tags: java, text-segmentation

The sentence String is expected to be a bunch of words separated by spaces, e.g. “Now is the time”.
showWords job is to output the words of the sentence one per line.

It is my homework, and I am trying, as you can see from the code below. I can not figure out how to and which loop to use to output word by word... please help.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the sentence");
        String sentence = in.nextLine();

        showWords(sentence);
}

    public static void showWords(String sentence) {
        int space = sentence.indexOf(" ");
        sentence = sentence.substring(0,space) + "\n" + sentence.substring(space+1);
        System.out.println(sentence);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a homework question, I will not give you the exact code but I want you to look at the method `split` in the `String`-class. And then I would recommend a for-loop.

Another alternative is to replace in your String until there are no more spaces left (this can be done both with a loop and without a loop, depending on how you do it)

Comment: The `replace` method will handle all occurrences of the space char with a single method call.  No looping needed.

Comment: @nhgrif That method yes, but there are other alternative methods (such as replaceFirst, or using substring like the OP seems to have attempted at already). `replace` might be the easiest solution of course.

Comment: What about multiple spaces? Regex replacement is a better choice

Comment: @Bohemian I will leave that for the OP to decide. That decision is not mine to make. You could also think of two spaces in a row as "a word of length zero" in the middle.

Comment: "A word of length zero"... Nice riposte :)

Answer (score 1):

Using regex you could use a one-liner:

```
System.out.println(sentence.replaceAll("\\s+", "\n"));
```

with the added benefit that multiple spaces won't leave blank lines as output.

---

If you need a simpler `String` methods approach you could use `split()` as

```
String[] split = sentence.split(" ");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (String word : split) {
    if (word.length() > 0) { // eliminate blank lines
        sb.append(word).append("\n");
    }
}
System.out.println(sb);
```

---

If you need an even more bare bones approach (down to `String` indexes) and more on the lines of your own code; you would need to wrap your code inside a loop and tweak it a bit.

```
int space, word = 0;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

while ((space = sentence.indexOf(" ", word)) != -1) {
    if (space != word) { // eliminate consecutive spaces
      sb.append(sentence.substring(word, space)).append("\n");
    }
    word = space + 1;
}

// append the last word
sb.append(sentence.substring(word));

System.out.println(sb);
```

Comment: The question is about a homework assignment.  Posting an outright answer isn't particularly helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right path. Your showWords method works for the first word, you just have to have it done until there are no words.

Loop through them, preferably with a while loop. If you use the while loop, think about when you need it to stop, which would be when there are no more words.

To do this, you can either keep an index of the last word and search from there(until there are no more), or delete the last word until the sentence string is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Java's `String` class has a `replace` method which you should look into.  That'll make this `homework` pretty easy.

[String.replace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29)

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

Use the split method of the String class to split the input string on the space character delimiter so you end up with a String array of words.

Then loop through that array using a modified for loop to print each item of the array.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


    public class Test {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("Enter the sentence");
            String sentence = in.nextLine();

            showWords(sentence);
    }

        public static void showWords(String sentence) {
            String[] words = sentence.split(' ');
            for(String word : words) {
             System.out.println(word);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: The question is about a homework assignment.  Posting an outright answer isn't particularly helpful.